# programmatically write to an Apple Numbers spreadsheet?

Tags: applescript

Is it possible to programmatically write an Apple Numbers spreadsheet in iOS/Windows.? We are developing an app and would like to be able to share the data it creates in a pre formatted spreadsheet using the users.

Any pointers or suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up applescript, and choose File->Open Dictionary.  Choose "Numbers" and it will show you every single command you can use.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in either Windows or iOS.